# Using macro to check null values

Tags: c, macros

My C code contains many functions with pointers to different structs as parameters which shouldn't be NULL pointers. To make my code more readable, I decided to replace this code:

```
if(arg1==NULL || arg2==NULL || arg3==NULL...) {
    return SOME_ERROR;
}
```

With that macro:

```
NULL_CHECK(arg1,arg2,...)
```

How should I write it, if the number of args is unknown and they can point to different structs? (I work in C99)

Answer (score 7):

IMO the most maintainable solution is to write multiple separate calls rather than trying to get "clever" about it.

for example, Win32 programmers use  a VERIFY macro which runs an assertion at debug time (the macro ensures that the assertions are stripped out of release code);  It's not unusual to see functions which start like this:

```
int foo(void* arg1, char* str, int n)
{
    VERIFY( arg1 != NULL );
    VERIFY( str != NULL );
    VERIFY( n > 0 );
```

Obviously, you could very easily condense those 3 lines into a single line, but the macro works best when you don't.  If you put them onto separate lines, then a failed assertion will tell you which of the three conditions have not been met, whereas putting them all in the same statement only tells you that something has failed, leavng you to figure out the rest.

Comment: +1; it's not generally a good idea to write C macros that change the syntax of the language (here, by including a return statement in the macro definition).   Using assertions like this is a much better approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use a macro, then I recommend using a macro that takes a single argument:

```
#define NULL_CHECK(val)  if (val == NULL) return SOME_ERROR;
```

You can then write:

```
NULL_CHECK(s1.member1);
NULL_CHECK(p2->member2);
```

Etc.  One of the advantages is that you can incorporate error reporting or logging accurately to identify the first invalid member like this.  With a single composite condition, you only know that at least one of them is invalid, but not exactly which one.

If you must deal with a variable number of arguments, then you need to investigate [`Boost::Preprocessor`](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor), which will work in C as well as C++.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I think it's a great idea to hide a `return` statement inside a macro, but such a macro could be written like:

```
#define NULL_CHECK(...)                                 \
  do {                                                  \
    void *_p[] = { __VA_ARGS__ };                       \
    int _i;                                             \
    for (_i = 0; _i < sizeof(_p)/sizeof(*_p); _i++) {   \
      if (_p[_i] == NULL) {                             \
        return SOME_ERROR;                              \
      }                                                 \
    }                                                   \
  } while(0)
```

Basically, expand the varargs into an array and loop over the indexes.

Comment: This is not only a needlessly complicated way to do something very simple, it is also more inefficient than the original code. I'm not familiar with variable argument list macros, but I suspect they aren't typesafe? If so, this code is also far more dangerous than the original one.

Comment: @Lundin To be clear I'm not advocating the use of this code, but I found it to be a curious way to (ab)use the preprocessor to enumerate arguments of a variadic macro (which I think is more or less what the OP was trying to figure out).  The macro is not typesafe, but the generated code is (well, as type safe as using a `void *` can be).  As far as efficiency is concerned, I'll defer to the old quote about premature optimization. I'm skeptical that it would cause an observable impact in all but the most extreme cases.

Comment: In my experience, most optimizers don't perform loop unrolling unless you ask for it specifically, since it could lead to an increase in program size.